# Silo Multi-tenant Flutter app using AWS Amplify with one frontend

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify, multi-tenant, flutter-aws-amplify

I'm building a multi-tenant app with Flutter using AWS Amplify.

My regulatory requirement makes it so I must have separate databases and storage(all user data) for each tenant.

The Flutter web version of the app is hosted on AWS Amplify Hosting, so as of now I have a full CI/CD pipeline to commit the app in the staging environment, then make a pull request to deploy it to the production environment.

My issue is, that after creating this process I discovered that each AWS Amplify Frontend can only have 1 backend connected to it.

This makes it impossible(at least from what I know until now) to create multiple backend environments(each environment for each tenant) that have a shared frontend.

My idea was having a prefix that is a name of the tenant in every username, then in the shared login using that prefix I'll authenticate using the matching user pool and then have IAM credentials to access the rest of that tenant environment.

Discovering that you can't(from what I know up to now) connect multiple backend environments to a single frontend made this unfeasible...

Does anyone have an idea of how I can make this happen?

Any help would be very appreciated